# Нужно распараллелить обработку элементов массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

В примере ***5*** на сайте http://john16blog.blogspot.com/2012/05/python-queue.html показана эта задача, но с использованием ООП.

Моя цель: Сделать тот же функционал программы, но без использования ООП и вместо потоков, использовать процессы, чтобы избежать GIL.

Но мой код пока что работает не совсем корректно.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from queue import PriorityQueue


word = 10


def brute(q_in, q_out):
    while True:
        p = q_in.get()
        print(f'{Process().name} Получил: {p}')
        print(f'{Process().name} Выполнил: {p}')
        if p == word:
            q_out.put((num, p))
            q_in.task_done()
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = range(15)
    q_in = Queue()
    q_out = PriorityQueue()

    for i in numbers:
        q_in.put(i)

    processes = []
    counter = -1
    for _ in range(4):
        p = Process(target=brute, args=(q_in, q_out))
        num = counter + 1
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    out = []
    while not q_out.empty():
        out.append(q_out.get())

    print(out)
```

Comment: Мы приняли ваше сообщение о том, что ваш код работает не совсем корректно. Но не понятно, в чем это некорректность проявляется, а во-вторых - вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Мне нужно повторить функционал программы из примера на другом сайте, но не использовать ООП и вместо потоков использовать процессы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С пулом оно быстрее и компактнее

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
numbers = range(105000)
word = 999

def brute(p):
    print(f'{os.getpid()} Получил: {p}')
    print(f'{os.getpid()} Выполнил: {p}')
    if p == word:
        return p

pool = Pool(8)       # восемь воркеров

for ret in pool.imap_unordered(brute, numbers):
    if ret:
        print('got', ret)
        pool.terminate()
        break
```

map - применяет функцию ко списку или итератору.

imap - возвращает при этом итератор

imap_unordered - не ждет завершение предыдужих потоков. Например, 5ый элемент посчитался раньше 4ого - выкидываем его сразу не дожидаясь очереди. Избегаем простоя там где не важен порядок.

Указав chunksize можно ещё сэкономить на передаче заданий.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, почему мы здесь используем imap_unordered?